# Multiple parameters with function is not working

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to show result with use multiple parameters in function but my code unable to display result. Can anyone help me to know what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>How to write JavaScript?</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Using multiple parameters with function
function result( number1, number2, number3)
{
    document.write("your luck number is " + number1 + number2 + number3);
}


</script>

</head>

<body>
<hr>
<h2>Using multiple parameters with function</h2>
<input type="button" value="Result" onclick=result(3, 6, 9);>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enclose the inline JavaScript in `"`. 
Use this instead:

```
<input type="button" value="Result" onclick="result(3, 6, 9);">
```

[**example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FLFX3/)